# PHP how to replace multiple of the same string with another string?

Tags: php

Hello Lets pretend I have the following string: `Line Line Line Line Line`. I want to change it to `Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 Line 4 Line 5`. How can I do this? I tried using str_replace but that replaces all of them to line 1. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe start with [`explode()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: Explode, iterate over the array, and append the key... or you could use `preg_replace_callback`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by using `explode()` and loop through your pieces.

```
<?php
  $string = "Line Line Line Line Line";
  $pieces = explode(" ", $string);
  foreach ($pieces as $key => $value) {
    echo $value.' '.++$key.' ';      
  }
?>
```

Comment: Ok this works but lets say I have the following string and I want to add the numbers to the end of the word lines. "Line example text Line example text Line different example text" How would I add the numbers after the words line only?

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime. You need to play around with the code above and try a few things, you might need `preg_replace` @bobby

Comment: @bobby Use `preg_replace_callback` so you can add the previous integer value.